# mv command - don't overwrite files

Tags: mv

I want to `mv` files and not overwrite duplicates.  The `-b` switch only makes a single backup file, whereas I may have many.

According to the [`mv` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv):

> The backup suffix is '`~`', unless set with `--suffix` or `SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX`. The version control method may be selected via the `--backup` option or through the `VERSION_CONTROL` environment variable. Here are the values:
>
> **none, off**:
> never make backups (even if --backup is given)
> **numbered, t**:
> make numbered backups
> **existing, nil**:
> numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
> **simple, never**:
> always make simple backups

I think I want to use the 'existing, nil' option... but I can't figure out how to call that.

If my command is:

```
mv $src $dest
```

How can I implement the 'existing, nil' option?

Comment: This answer has a good response about using `cp` instead of `mv`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9902

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable `existing` or `nil` (or any of the other options), pass them as values for the `--backup` option:

```
mv --backup=existing "$src" "$dest"
mv --backup=nil "$src" "$dest"
```

Be warned that this does not do what you want:

```
$ mkdir foo bar
$ cp blah/* foo
$ cp blah/* bar
$ mv --backup=nil bar/* foo/* -t blah
mv: will not overwrite just-created ‘blah/a.jpg’ with ‘foo/a.jpg’
mv: will not overwrite just-created ‘blah/b.ogv’ with ‘foo/b.ogv’
mv: will not overwrite just-created ‘blah/cd ef.JpG’ with ‘foo/cd ef.JpG’
```

You actually want `numbered`/`t`:

```
$ mv --backup=numbered bar/* foo/* -t blah
$ ls blah 
a.jpg  a.jpg.~1~  a.jpg.~2~  b.ogv  b.ogv.~1~  b.ogv.~2~  cd ef.JpG  cd ef.JpG.~1~  cd ef.JpG.~2~
```

Comment: that seems really cryptic. What is the backup option for?

Comment: @ConnorLeech to control the backup settings?

Answer (score 0):

```
mv --backup=existing $src $dest
```

or

```
mv --backup=nil $src $dest
```

Comment: After many attempts, I got the syntax working -- but the nil option did not work.  --backup=t  does though.    THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
mv --backup=t "$src/$file" "$dest"
```

Comment: for details see `man mv`